# How do I setup DNS names and static IPs for an Ubuntu virtualbox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ip, dns

I have Ubuntu installed on VirtualBox, on top of a Windows 8 host. How can I setup a static IP and DNS name for this virtual machine that other virtual machines will see?

Comment: I'd refer you to [How to make a machine accessible from the LAN using its hostname](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname), except that you want to do this with a Windows host… You should ask Windows experts, not Unix experts.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a DNS server of write down the host's name in the [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) file of each system you have.

Comment: Where should I setup DNS server? On Ubuntu guest or on Windows host?
I can use /etc/hosts instead of it, but first I need provide static  IPs, isn't? How I do this?

Comment: You can set up the DNS server anywhere. You just have to configure each host to use it. It will be easier if each host has a static IP address but what do you mean by "_How I do this?_"